# How can I find the first monday of current month using cygwin bash date utilty?

Tags: bash, cygwin

I need to know the first monday of the current month using Cygwin bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A one-liner--I hope it's correct

d=$(date -d `date +%Y%m"01"` +%u);date -d `date +%Y%m"0"$(((9-$d)%7))`

the variable `d` contains the day of week (1..7) where 1 is Monday
then I print the current year and month changing the day with `$((9-$d))`

Comment: `$(( 9 - $d ))` will yield the wrong result for example if the 1st is a Monday.

Comment: Almost ;-) The transformation of d to date first monday you are looking for would have to be `1->1`, `2->7`, `3->6`, `4->5`, `5->4`, `6->3`, `7->2`. `(9-d)%7`
gives `1->1`, `2->0`, `3->6`, `4->5`, `5->4`, `6->3`, `7->2`, but `0` is not a
valid day of the week. So it will not work for Tuesdays.

Comment: Try `$(( (8-i) % 7 + 1 ))` :-)

Comment: Hey dude that was a quick one-liner ;) and he question required the first monday of the current month, no mention of tuesdays ...

Comment: Well, the first of the month can still be a Tuesday, that's what I meant. Your one-liner was mathematically more advanced than my answer even in its first version so I wanted to make sure it gets perfect :)

Answer (score 2):

### One Liner:

`d=$(date -d "today 1300" '+%Y%m01'); w=$(date -d $d '+%w'); i=$(( (8 - $w) % 7)); answer=$(( $d + $i ));`

The result is stored in `$answer`.  It uses working variables `$d`, `$w`, and `$i`.

#### Proof (assuming you just ran the one liner above):

`echo $answer; echo $(date -d $answer '+%w')`

Expected Result: Monday of current month in YYYYMMDD.  On the next line, a 1 for the day of the week.

#### Expanded Proof (checks the next 100 month's Mondays):

`for x in {1..100}; do d=$(date -d "+$x months 1300" '+%Y%m01'); w=$(date -d $d '+%w'); i=$(( (8 - $w) % 7)); answer=$(( $d + $i )); echo $answer; echo $(date -d $answer '+%w'); done | egrep -B1 '^[^1]$'`

Expected Result: NOTHING

(If there are results, something is broken)

### Breaking it down

The first statement gets the first day of the current month, and stores that in `$d`, formatted as YYYYMMDD.

The second statement gets the day of the week number of the date `$d`, and stores that in `$w`.

The third statement computes the increment of days to add and stores it in `$i`.  Zero is perfectly valid here, because...

The last statement computes the sum of the date `$d` (as an integer) and the increment `$i` (as an integer).  This works because the domain of the `$i` is 0 to 6, and we will always start at the first day of the month.  This can quickly be converted back to a date variable (see Proof for example of this).

This has been tested on BASH v4.1 (CentOS 6), v4.4 (Ubuntu), and v5 (Archlinux)

Answer (score 1):

This should do it, but I have no Cygwin here to test:

```
#!/bin/bash

# get current year and month:
year=$( date +"%Y" )
month=$( date +"%m" )

# for the first 7 days in current month :
for i in {1..7}
do
  # get day of week (dow) for that date:
  dow=$( date -d "${year}-${month}-${i}" +"%u" )" "

  # if dow is 1 (Monday):
  if [ "$dow" -eq 1 ]
  then
    # print date of that Monday in default formatting:
    date -d "${year}-${month}-${i}"
    break
  fi
done
```

See manpage `date(1)` for more information.

Comment: jaro you answer works too... thank you... I am marking @
user2314737 answer as accepted since it is a oneliner..